# Suitable web framework for the following scenario

Tags: java, web-frameworks

I have the following scenario:
I have a view in an Oracle server and all Iwant is to show that view in a web browser, along with an input field or two for basic filtering. No users, no authentication, just this view maybe with a column or two linking to a second page for master detail viewing. The children are just string descriptions of the columns of the master that contain IDs. No inserts or updates.
The question is which is the JAVA based web framework of choice that can accomplish the above in the minimum amount of

1. code lines
2. code time(subjective but also kind of objective if someone has expirience with more than one or two frameworks)
3. configuration effort
4. deployment effort and requirements.
5. dependencies and mem footprint

Also:
6. Oracle APEX is not an option.

3,4 and 5 are maybe the same in the sense that they are everything except the functionality coding.
I want something that I can compile, deploy by just FTPing to the database host, run and forget. (e.g. For the deployment aspect, Hudson way comes in mind (java -jar hudson.war and that's all)).

Also: 3,4 have priority over 1 and 2. (Explanation with a rant: I dont mind coding a lot as long as it is application code and not "why do we still use javascript over http for everything" code)

Thanks.

EDIT 1: ROO attempt.
First I tried Spring Roo but here is what happened and it is exactly the kind of stuff i want to avoid:

1. Downloaded Roo (setup env vars, path, etc)
2. Saw that it requires Maven (1st smell)
3. Installed maven
4. Setup my project in roo shell
5. Tried to run it and it could not build because maven could not locate artifacts.
6. Searched the web and eventually found that I need to tweak the generated pom because of a problem between springsource repositories and maven central caused when Oracle is used because of a minor bug in ROO that includes the maven repo and not the spring one... etc...etc..
7. Abandonded Roo because:
   **I wanted a simple one page presentation of a table view in a locally installed database, and after 30 minutes I had no progress except for searching maven forums for why maven cant find sth called an "artifact" in a list of sth called "repository".**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Spring MVC and [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo). the latter will generate you Spring application in a matter of minutes with the database access and then you can add your filtering.

Answer (score 0):

The hudson-like deployment should be easy if you're happy with the features an embedded servlet container like jetty or winstone can provide. Just add a main class that fires up the server and sets a few config variables. That should be possible with any java web framework.

Here's how hudson did it:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/02/11/hudson-became-self-executable

Comment: I know. For jetty though the deps are too much, especially with the latest version from eclipse it seems that they force you to include everything...

Answer (score 0):

try [(µ)Micro](http://micro-docs.simplegames.ca) and see if it works for you. It is Open Source, of course, and I also provided a couple of useful [examples](https://github.com/florinpatrascu/micro-examples) to start with. HTH - florin